# Match everything but regular expression inside the string

Tags: regex

I am trying write a regular expression that will match everying in between two specific words but will also discard all substrings of a specific pattern.

For example, if the given sentence is:  'START this is [*9-11*0] a dummy [3-*1] sentence END', I want to write a regular expression to get the answer: this is a dummy sentence

If I only want to match everything in between the words START and END, I can write regular expression: START(.*?)END

But I also want to discard all the patterns in between that starts with [ followed by any combination of  numbers, hyphen and * and ending with ].

How do I do that?

Comment: In short, you can’t do this in one step. You must *first* match the whole content, *then* use another regex to match unwanted text and replace it with blank (ie delete it)

Comment: @user40739, didn't the regex below serve the purpose?

Comment: @user40739 Did any of the posted answers work out?

Answer (score 1):

This [regex](https://regex101.com/r/fXZs7H/1) will serve your purpose

```
/START|(\[[^]]*\]\s)|END/g
```

A demo can be seen above regex101 link.

Explanation -

- three alternatives

  1. First START as it is
  2. second anything between literals `[` and `]` except `[`
  3. last END literal as it is

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments you can use a 2 step approach.

First match from START to END with no occurrences of start or END in between.

```
\bSTART\b((?:(?!\b(?:START|END)\b).)*)\bEND\b
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uK6S6j/1).

Then remove the square brackets with the allowed chars using a repeated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
\[[0-9*-]+]
```

Due to the replacements, there might occur double space gaps. At then end you can replace all 2 or more spaces with a single space, and  trim the string to remove leading and training whitespace chars of the whole string.

There is no language listed, but for example using Javascript:

```js
const regex = /\bSTART\b((?:(?!\b(?:START|END)\b).)*)\bEND\b/g;
const s = "START this is [*9-11*0] a dummy [3-*1] sentence END";
Array.from(
  s.matchAll(regex), m => console.log(
    m[1].replace(/\[[0-9*-]+]/g, '').replace(/\s{2}/g, ' ').trim()
  )
);
```